# Python assert on property set

Tags: python

Is it possible to make a property assert when it is changed (for the purpose of debugging)?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def set_my_property(self, value):
        self.my_property = value
        # TODO: mark my_property so that if it gets set again, an assert
        # is triggered

c = MyClass()
c.set_my_property(4)

# any of these lines would cause an assertion
c.set_my_property(8)
c.my_property = 123
```

Comment: could you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:
Is this what you're looking for?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.trigger = False
        self._my_property = 0

    def set_my_property(self, value):
        if self.trigger:
            raise Exception("WHOOPS!")
        self._my_property = value
        # TODO: mark my_property so that if it gets set again, an assert
        # is triggered
        self.trigger = True

    def get_my_property(self):
        return self._my_property

    my_property = property(get_my_property, set_my_property, None)

c = MyClass()
c.set_my_property(4)

# any of these lines would cause an assertion
c.set_my_property(8)
c.my_property = 123
```

Comment: `c.my_property = 123` won't assert this way.

Comment: My bad, I forgot using the **property()** builtin

Comment: You need to make it a `property` if you want to access it as `c.my_property = 123`

Comment: That raises an exception, rather than an assert :-)

Comment: Eh, you can make it into an assert by...well, including an assert. It's a proof of concept, ok? :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a boolean to check if the value has been set before:

EDIT: But you want a property, so you'll need to create one:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_property_set = False
        self._my_property = None

    def set_my_property(self, value):
        self._my_property = value
        assert not self.my_property_set,"my_property already set"
        self.my_property_set = True

    def get_my_property(self):
        return self._my_property

    my_property = property(get_my_property, set_my_property, None)

c = MyClass()
c.set_my_property(4)

# any of these lines would cause an assertion
c.set_my_property(8)
c.my_property = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = None

    @property
    def bar(self): return self._bar

    @bar.setter:
    def bar(self, value):
        assert value != some_constant # your assert condition
        self._bar = value

    @bar.deleter:
    def bar(self, value):
        assert value != some_constant # your assert condition
        self._bar = None
```

Comment: shouldn't `_bar` be a member variable rather than a class variable?